# SQL related wonky error if there is no HTTP in the URL

Tags: sql, oracle, http, httpwebrequest

```
select
wu.ACCOUNT_NUMBER as WS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
wu.LIFETIME_REVENUE as WS_LIFETIME_REVENUE,
wu.FIRST_NAME||' '||wu.LAST_NAME as WS_ACCOUNT_NAME,
wu.PRIMARY_EMAIL as WS_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
wu.TIME_CREATED as WS_ACCOUNT_TIME_CREATED,
wuu.URL as BUSINESS_URL
from
WUSER wu
left outer join WUSER_URL wuu on wu.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = wuu.ACCOUNT_NUMBER

where
wu.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 123456789;
```

URL displayed on the screen is hyperlink and should take us to the website on clicking it. Problem is that it works only and only when it has a HTTP protocol attached prior to it in the Oracle db.

for example, **it works** when the url in db is http://www.google.com or http://google.com
but **it FAILS** when the url is google.com or www.google.com

Our client is very specific about this requirement and wants to be able to hop over to the website when there is no HTTP to the URL record in the db.

**What are the possible solutions? Can I write a conditional insert to check record by record if there is HTTP, and if not, then append it somehow ?

If yes, please tell me the SQL too**

Please Help!!!!!!

Comment: I fail to see how this is an SQL problem - sounds more like a clientside/display problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to check the data before it's being inserted, and pre-pend the `HTTP://`?

Conditional code to put `HTTP://` in front of the string could be...

```
CASE WHEN UPPER(wuu.URL) LIKE 'HTTP://%'
THEN wuu.UR
ELSE 'HTTP://' || wuu.URL
END
```

(It's only on several lines to make it easier to read.)

Comment: how can i use upper in the string to eliminate the case-sensitivity. I'm sorry but I'm not a technical person.

Comment: For a non-techy, that's a very good catch.  I've updated the answer to cater for case-sensitive environments.

Comment: Ok, now the problem is that it is appending http:// even when there is no record in URL. Can we solve it ?

Comment: `CASE WHEN x = '' THEN x WHEN x LIKE 'fu' THEN bar ELSE wibble END`

Comment: I just wanted to bring it your attention hence I unmarked your answer. I'm not that active on this site. I couldn't find any other way of rephrasing my question than writing it in a comment. Sorry for that. Cheers!